# Why does PythonShell.run work with two arguments and using a .then() while doesn't with three arguments (callback function as third)?

Tags: python, node.js, promise, callback

I have this script running in Node.js, which works fine:

```
const {PythonShell} = require("python-shell");

PythonShell.run("hello.py", null).then(result => {
    try{
        console.log(result[0]);
    }
    catch(err){
        console.log("err = ", err);
    }
});
```

The script "hello.py" in Python only has the instruction "print('Hello from Python')", so when running this Node.js script, the output is 'Hello from Python'.

But if I modify it a bit to not use .then(...) but a callback function, then I don't get any output, and it is because it never enters the callback function, as I have corroborated putting a "console.log" in the beginning:

```
const {PythonShell} = require("python-shell");

PythonShell.run("hello.py", null, function (err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(result[0]);
});
```

I have tried putting an options object in the second argument that has the absolute path to the "hello.py" file but it still does not work.

What am I missing?

The version of python-shell is 5.0.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use callbacks with `PythonShell.run()`.

Take a look at the [source for the `run` function](https://github.com/extrabacon/python-shell/blob/304da70b57b586bafdeb55dfada02431efb0c49e/index.ts#L318), it only takes two arguments. This means your third argument (the callback function) is never seen, as the function isn't written to take one.

The reason you are supposed to use `.then()` is because `PythonShell.run()` returns a [Promise](https://blog.logrocket.com/guide-promises-node-js/#consuming-a-promise).

Comment: Is it possible that it changed with the version? I have seen some examples in which they use it with a third argument: https://github.com/extrabacon/python-shell/issues/22

Comment: Given that the issue you linked is from 8 years ago, yes I would imagine its changed since then 